# Get the most recent tweet on Twitter overall

Tags: api, twitter, tweets

I'm creating an application using the Twitter API and want to get the last Tweet tweeted. Not the last Tweet from people I follow or something like this, the actual last Tweet from all around the world in that moment. Is there a possible way for that?

Answer (score 1):

Not really possible. Best you can do is get the latest tweet from an approximately one percent sampling of all tweets.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way you'd be able to do that accurately would be to consume the Twitter firehose. As an alternative, you could use the `statuses/sample` realtime API to get Tweets from 1% of the current volume of the firehose. Another option would be to use `statuses/filter` with a geofence over the whole planet, but again this would just be a 1% dataset.